# How can I get the latest pre-release release for my github repo - bash

Tags: bash, github

To get the latest release I can run:

```
curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/maxisme/notifi/releases/latest" | grep '"tag_name":' | sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'
```

But I want the latest release tag_name that is a draft/pre-release?

Comment: So the output you're after should be: `refs/tags/0.9.9` ?

Comment: The output returned from curl and so use jq to parse the json

Comment: @0stone0 ideally 0.9.9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use the following route to get [**all** the releases](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-releases):

```
https://api.github.com/repos/maxisme/notifi/releases
```

Using a Json tool like [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) we can easily filter all the object to only show those where `prerelease: true`, then, extract the `tag_name` of that latest release like so:

```
jq -r 'map(select(.prerelease)) | first | .tag_name'
```

Where :
<sub>[JqPlay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/hqMKLrG4U6)</sub>

1. `select(.prerelease)` filters to items where `prerelease: true`
2. `first` get the first object in the array of releases
3. `.tag_name` shows the value of the `tag_name` key

---

Combining this to a bash one-liner:

```sh
jq -r 'map(select(.prerelease)) | first | .tag_name' <<< $(curl --silent https://api.github.com/repos/maxisme/notifi/releases)
```

Prints:

```
0.9.9
```

---

If you're not sure there will be a `prerelease` on the project, we can add a fallback to the [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) call:

```
map(select(.prerelease)) | first | .tag_name // "Not found"
```

This will now show `Not found` if there's no `tag_name` on a `prelease`.

Comment: Releases are not returned in time order, or apparently any particular order. So this won't work reliably. See: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/8226#discussioncomment-7704448